# For some reason my other processes do not receive the data from my first process (MPI in C)

Tags: c, mpi

What I am trying to do is make an array of 1s and 0s and split the entire array into 4 processes (doesn't matter how many 4 is my test case) and have each process print its rank, length of array, and the array itself. But when I run the code I get something like this:

```
Enter length and sequence length
100 4
1101000010110110101110101
1110101001111100011100100
1011100110011100001011010
1000110101001000001000111

Rank: 0   Length: 25
```

I am not sure why this happens. For some reason I cannot pass data properly to other processes (I am very new to MPI)

Here is my code:

```
#include "ore_header.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

srand(time(NULL));

    int     my_rank, p;
    int     total;
    int     length;
    int     seq_length;
    void    generate_sequence(int *arr, int n);
    int     subsequence_check(int *arr,int n, int m);


    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

    MPI_Request     reqs[p];
    MPI_Status      stats[p];
    int     p_length;
    int     p_total[p];
    int     *buf[p];
    if (my_rank == 0) {
        printf("Enter length and sequence length\n");
        scanf("%d %d",&length, &seq_length);
        p_length = length / p;
        for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
            buf[i] = (int*)malloc(p_length*sizeof(int));
            generate_sequence(buf[i], p_length); //Generates a sequence
            MPI_Isend(&buf[i], p_length, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[i]); //Send each buffer to each sequence
            MPI_Wait(&reqs[my_rank], &stats[my_rank]); //Wait for data to be sent
        }
    }
    MPI_Irecv(&buf[my_rank], p_length, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[my_rank]); //Receive Data from process 0
    MPI_Wait(&reqs[my_rank], &stats[my_rank]); //Wait for communication to end
    printf("\nRank: %d   Length: %d\n",my_rank,p_length);
    for (int i = 0; i < p_length; i++) {
        printf("%d",buf[i]);
    }

    //tot = subsequence_check(buf,length,seq_length);
    //printf("\n\nTotal: %d\n",tot);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return (0);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the feed back I have fixed the issues and now it works as intended:

```
#include "ore_header.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    srand(time(NULL));

    int     my_rank, p;
    int     total;
    int     length;
    int     flag;
    int     seq_length;
    void    generate_sequence(int *arr, int n);
    int     subsequence_check(int *arr,int n, int m);


    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);


    int     p_length;
    int     *buf[p];
    if (my_rank == 0) {
        printf("Enter length and sequence length\n");
        scanf("%d %d",&length, &seq_length);
        p_length = length / p;
        for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
            buf[i] = (int*)malloc(p_length*sizeof(int));
            generate_sequence(buf[i], p_length);
            MPI_Send(buf[i], p_length, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            printf("Data sent to process %d\n", i);
        }
    }
    MPI_Bcast(&p_length, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    buf[my_rank] = (int*)malloc(p_length*sizeof(int));
    MPI_Status      stats[p];
    MPI_Request     reqs[p];
    MPI_Irecv(buf[my_rank], p_length, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[my_rank]);
    while(1) {
        MPI_Test(&reqs[my_rank], &flag, &stats[my_rank]);
        if (flag) break;
    }
    printf("\nData received on process: %d   Length: %d\n",my_rank,p_length);
    for (int i = 0; i < p_length; i++) {
        printf("%d",buf[my_rank][i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    //tot = subsequence_check(buf,length,seq_length);
    //printf("\n\nTotal: %d\n",tot);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return (0);
}
```

and here is my output:

```
Enter length and sequence length
100 4
0101100011001110110010011
Data sent to process 0
0010011010000001001010111
Data sent to process 1
0011111111101101100000111
Data sent to process 2
0000000100010011100001111
Data sent to process 3

Data received on process: 0   Length: 25
0101100011001110110010011

Data received on process: 1   Length: 25
0010011010000001001010111

Data received on process: 2   Length: 25
0011111111101101100000111

Data received on process: 3   Length: 25
0000000100010011100001111
```

Comment: What is `p_length`'s value when `MPI_Irecv`ing?

Comment: if I make the length n then p_length is n\p where p is the number of processes

Comment: Check again. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MPI_Isend()` needs a pointer to the buffer and `&buf[i]` is a pointer to a pointer to a buffer. Hence, could you try  `MPI_Isend(buf[i],...`?

In addition, the request `reqs[i]` is set in `MPI_Isend()` but `MPI_Wait()` only checks the completion of `reqs[my_rank]`. Therefore, another modification can be suggested:

```
MPI_Isend(buf[i], p_length, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[i]); //Send each buffer to each sequence
MPI_Wait(&reqs[i], &stats[i]); //Wait for data to be sent
```

Calling `MPI_Wait()` right after `MPI_Isend()` seems equivalent to calling `MPI_Send()`, in particular if the returned MPI_Status is not tested by something like [`MPI_Test_cancelled()`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Test_cancelled.3.php). In the present case, the successive calls to `MPI_Wait()` could easily be replaced by a single call to [`MPI_Waitall()`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Waitall.3.php) at the end of the for loop.

Edit: the question of @a3f on the value of `p_length` in `MPI_Irecv()` on ranks other than 0 is still valid...

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, can you explain why my &buf[i] did not work? I thought buf[i] hold the value of a pointer? or does it hold the pointer's address?

Comment: `buf[i]` is a pointer to `buf[i][0]`, the first item of the buffer: its value is the adress of `buf[i][0]`. This exactly what `MPI_Isend()` needs. On the contrary `&buf[i]` is a pointer to the pointer `buf[i]`. Its value is the adress of `buf[i]`, which is not the first item of a buffer. `&buf[i]` is a pointer to a pointer to the buffer. That is one pointer too much!